# Remove from Everything but these values

Tags: c#, string, parsing

I have this these values that I need to keep in my strings

```
string[] units = new string[] {
                "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight",
                "nine", "ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen",
                "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen",
            };

string[] tens = new string[] { "", "", "twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety" };

string[] scales = new string[] { "hundred", "thousand", "million", "billion", "trillion" };
string[] seperators = new string[]{ "and" }
```

I need to remove everything else except these values
so from this text:

> DUE IN THIRTY SEVEN DAYS

I want to get this:

> THIRTY SEVEN

Comment: What have you tried so far? This looks like you're just posting the requirements, not what efforts you have made thus far.

Comment: My first instinct here is "regex": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx

Comment: Gotta be blunt: at your rep level, you should know better than to post without showing any effort.

Comment: @paqogomez: hehe, you *kinda* got me there. But that answer did get the most upvotes (a staggering total of 1).

Comment: @musical_coder and a fine answer it was :)

Comment: It was almost a -1 for the mis-spelling of `seperators` *(sic)* alone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var strValue = "DUE IN THIRTY SEVEN DAYS".ToLower().Split(' ');

var numbers = (from u in units
               join s in strValue on u equals s
               select u);
Console.Write(string.Join(" ", numbers));
```

[.Net Fiddle](http://dotnetfiddle.net/ONl9q6)

Comment: I did take some shortcuts with your units variable. But you can get the general idea with this code.

Comment: Thanks I did not even know where to start.